# Query returning Count of rows and assigning to Int variable

Tags: c#, sql

Im selecting the count of how many rows in my query. I need to assign that to a int variable. How would I accomplish this?

Display.aspx.cs

```
            **int TotalYesVotes;**
            Ratings GetYesVotes = new Ratings();
            DataTable DATotalYesVotes = GetYesVotes.GetTotalYesVotes();
            **//How do i assign that count to TotalYesVotes**
```

Business layer

```
     public DataTable GetTotalYesVotes()
     {

         DLRatings DlTotalyesVotes = new DLRatings();
         return DlTotalyesVotes.GetTotalYesVotes();

     }
```

My data layer

```
    public DataTable GetTotalNoVotes()
    {
        //get database connection string from config file
        string strConectionString o= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseConnection"];

        //set up sql
        string StrSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM Ratings WHERE (PicRating = 2) AND (PicID = 2)";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter daObj = new SqlDataAdapter(StrSql, strConectionString))
        {

            //fill data table
            daObj.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
        }
```

Comment: If the purpose of `GetTotalNoVotes` is to retrieve a scalar value, why are you returning a datatable?

Answer (score 2):

You should change the data retrieval around a lot:

```
   public int GetTotalNoVotes()
    {
        //get database connection string from config file
        string strConectionString o= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseConnection"];

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) AS Expr1 FROM Ratings WHERE (PicRating = 2) AND (PicID = 2)", conn);

        object oValue = oCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Close();

        if (oValue == DBNull.Value) {
           return 0;
        } else {
          return Convert.ToInt32(oValue);
        }
   }
```